# Drag image FROM iframe (running BING image search) TO parent - is this possible?

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone know if it's possible to drag an image from BING search results, to a DIV in the iframe's parent?

If you drag an image from BING's image search results to notepad, it drops the image URL (sort of - it's the URL to the BING full-size image).

I've managed to support drop of the image from another browser Window, but not from a child iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function noopHandler(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
        }

        function drop(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault(); 
            var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
            alert(imageUrl);
        }   

        $(window).ready(function() {
            var dropbox = document.getElementById('flashcards_div');

            dropbox.addEventListener('dragenter', noopHandler, false);
            dropbox.addEventListener('dragexit', noopHandler, false);
            dropbox.addEventListener('dragover', noopHandler, false);
            dropbox.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);      
        });
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flashcards_div" style="height:500px;"></div>
    <div>
        <iframe src="http://www.bing.com/images" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```